# Uploading a JSON file and using it

Tags: javascript

How can I upload a JSON file on some click on a button on my web page say "import", and use it to store in a variable to use and update it using JavaScript.

I have gone through the other posts but could not find any answer.

I am saving the JSON variable using this function:

```
function save(filename, data){

    if(!data) {
        alert('error : No data')
        return;
    }

    if(typeof data === "object"){
        data = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 4)
    }

    var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/json'}),
        e    = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
        a    = document.createElement('a')

    a.download = filename
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    a.dataset.downloadurl =  ['text/json', a.download, a.href].join(':')
    e.initMouseEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null)
    a.dispatchEvent(e)
 }
```

This is working fine and it downloads the file on clicking another button say "export".
How upload this file back and make a JSON variable of this file data?

Comment: Without a server side code?

Comment: yes without the server side code. @PraveenKumar

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Without server side code, your best approach may be to provide a `textarea` element for the user to copy/paste the JSON into, and then parse it using `JSON.parse`.

You could even go as far as to use something like [Ace Editor](https://ace.c9.io) to provide syntax highlighting for JSON - you can see it in action on the [Ace Editor Kitchen Sink Demo](https://ace.c9.io/build/kitchen-sink.html) - select JSON from the dropdown list in the top left.

---

### Edit:

Turns out I was wrong.  Here is a fiddle demonstrating the FileReader in use, which is exactly what you need:

https://jsfiddle.net/Ln37kqc0/

Here is the code:

**Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById('import').onclick = function() {
    var files = document.getElementById('selectFiles').files;
  console.log(files);
  if (files.length <= 0) {
    return false;
  }

  var fr = new FileReader();

  fr.onload = function(e) { 
  console.log(e);
    var result = JSON.parse(e.target.result);
    var formatted = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
        document.getElementById('result').value = formatted;
  }

  fr.readAsText(files.item(0));
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" id="selectFiles" value="Import" /><br />
<button id="import">Import</button>
<textarea id="result"></textarea>
```

Comment: Meanwhile there is a newer, promise based interface that can be used to accomplish this task: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob#Extracting_data_from_a_blob

Answer (score 13):

I have got a way to use the uploaded json file, here is the way i found.

```
$("#inputFile").change(function(e) {
    onChange(e);
});

function onChange(event) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = onReaderLoad;
    reader.readAsText(event.target.files[0]);
}

function onReaderLoad(event){
    //alert(event.target.result);
    var obj = JSON.parse(event.target.result);
    alert(obj);
}
```

Comment: a fiddle provided will be much better

Answer (score 7):

**Basic upload File**:

```
    <input id="contentFile" type="file" accept="application/json" />
```

> ```
>   document.getElementById('contentFile').onchange = function(evt) {
>         try {
>             let files = evt.target.files;
>             if (!files.length) {
>                 alert('No file selected!');
>                 return;
>             }
>             let file = files[0];
>             let reader = new FileReader();
>             const self = this;
>             reader.onload = (event) => {
>                 console.log('FILE CONTENT', event.target.result);
>             };
>             reader.readAsText(file);
>         } catch (err) {
>             console.error(err);
>         }
>     }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the useful attribute for json only: accept="application/json"

Answer (score 3):

## [2021] Promise based approach

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36127648/uploading-a-json-file-and-using-it#comment115482690_36198572), you can make use of the newer blob api to easily get the file's value via:

```
await blob.text()
```

```js
const getJsonUpload = () =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    const inputFileElement = document.createElement('input')
    inputFileElement.setAttribute('type', 'file')
    inputFileElement.setAttribute('multiple', 'true')
    inputFileElement.setAttribute('accept', '.json')
    
    inputFileElement.addEventListener(
      'change',
      async (event) => {
        const { files } = event.target
        if (!files) {
          return
        }

        const filePromises = [...files].map(file => file.text())

        resolve(await Promise.all(filePromises))
      },
      false,
    )
    inputFileElement.click()
  })


document.getElementById('upload-button').onclick = async () => {
    const jsonFiles = await getJsonUpload()
  console.log({jsonFiles})
}
```

```html
<button id="upload-button">
Upload
</button>
```

Comment: I'd suggest that you should provide a minimal working example for your approach, since I believe it's better than the current top answer, but your current example is not quite minimal since the code for handling multiple file uploads is rather complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, works perfect

```
handleUploadFile = async(doc) => {
  let file = doc.target.files[0]
  let reader = new FileReader(file)

  // await reader.readAsDataURL(file)

  reader.readAsText(file)

  reader.onload = async(e) => {

    let aaa = e.target.result

    let content = await JSON.parse(aaa)
    console.log(content)

  }
}
```

Comment: This solution works but could use a little [more clarity](https://jsfiddle.net/81jvwzag/1/)

Answer (score 1):

With the newer Blob API, the [current top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36198572/4681187) can be simplified by skipping the `FileReader`:

```js
document.getElementById('import').onclick = function() {
  var files = document.getElementById('selectFiles').files;
  console.log(files);
  if (files.length <= 0) {
    return false;
  }
  files[0].text().then(function(text) { 
    console.log(text);
    var result = JSON.parse(text);
    var formatted = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
    document.getElementById('result').value = formatted;
  })
};
```

To explain the code a little: `files[0]` itself is a `File` object, which inherits from `Blob`, so `files[0].text()` is an asynchronous function that reads the content of the file into a string.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add the draggable option

Firs create your HTML

```
<div class="drag" id="drag_area">
        <input class="box_file disabled" type="file" name="files[]" id="file" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple />
        <label for="file"><strong>Choose save file</strong><span class="box__dragndrop"> or drag it here</span>.</label>
</div>
```

Than write out your JS

```
$("#drag_area").on('drag dragstart dragend dragover dragenter dragleave drop', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
})
.on('dragover dragenter', function () {
    $("#drag_area").addClass('dr_active');
    // this is needed if you wish to style your drag area on drag events
})
.on('dragleave dragend drop', function () {
    $("#drag_area").removeClass('dr_active');
    // this is needed if you wish to style your drag area on drag events
})
.on('drop', function (e) {
    let droppedFiles = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    let reader = new FileReader()
    reader.readAsDataURL(droppedFiles[0])
    reader.onloadend = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: reader.result,
        success: function (data) {
          console.log(JSON.parse(data)); // This is your JSON
        },
        error: function (request, error) {
            cliLog(2, "Upload", "Cant upload save file")
        }
    });
}
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd made a more general approach with support to customize upload button title and callback when load is done:

```js
function uploadJson(id, callback) {
    document.getElementById(id).onchange = function(evt) {
        try {
            let files = evt.target.files;
            if (!files.length) {
                alert('No file selected!');
                return;
            }
            let file = files[0];
            let reader = new FileReader();
            const self = this;
            reader.onload = (event) => {
                callback(event.target.result);
            };
            reader.readAsText(file);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    }
}

uploadJson('importJson', function (json) {
    console.log(json);
});
```

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('importJson').click()">import json</button>
<input id="importJson" value="import json" type="file" accept="application/json" style="display:none" />
```