# What is a good way to automatically access a file after it has been uploaded?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a input tag which I disabled and binded to another input tag to create a custom text together with the ability to open file explorer via it.

HTML:

```
<input id="fileInput" type="file" accept="application/JSON" style="display:none;" />

<input title="Load a existing JSON file from your PC" id="btnUploadJSON" type="button"  value="Upload JSON" 
onclick="document.getElementById('fileInput').click();"
onMouseOver="this.style.backgroundColor='#efcc00'"onMouseOut="this.style.backgroundColor='#eee600'"/>
```

I have looked at a example here [example of how to upload a json into variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36127648/uploading-a-json-file-and-using-it) but it uses 2 buttons. 1 to open explorer and second one to parse and display the json. I would like to achieve this only with 1 button. Ideally with something that checks if a file has been uploaded once file explorer closes and then automatically performs the import function.

So my question probably is, Is there a way to detect when file explorer closes and if a file has been selected?

Here is my JS function, the problem is it triggers before I can choose a file so length <= 0 is triggered before file explorer. Is it possible to make it wait until file explorer closes and then perform the onclick()?

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('btnUploadJSON').onclick = function() {
    //uploading a json file via file explorer
    var files = document.getElementById('fileInput').files
    console.log(files)
    if (files.length <= 0) {
        alert("Json file seems to be empty or incorrect format, please double check you are uploading the right file!")
        return false
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change this line:

```
- document.getElementById('btnUploadJSON').onclick = function() {
+ document.getElementById('fileInput').onchange = function() {
```